Reading Waveform from Teledyne Lecroy Wavesurfer 3054
I am trying to read the waveform data from a Teledyne LeCroy Wavesurfer 3054 using a pyvisa package I found on GitHub (https://github.com/SengerM/TeledyneLeCroyPy/tree/main). The problem is, when the script calls the get_waveform() method which then calls self.resource.read_raw() the program then halts on that line. I have also tried using pyvisa methods like read_binary_values() but the same problem occurs.
When I restart the oscilloscope then run the code I sometimes get the error: struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes for unpacking 4 bytes at offset 0 (actual buffer size is 0).
But the vast majority of time the code just get stuck on self.resource.read_raw()
Here is the script I'm running. It is just the first example from the above link.
import TeledyneLeCroyPy

o = TeledyneLeCroyPy.LeCroyWaveRunner('USB0::blah::blah::blah::9.1.0')

print(o.idn) # Pings e.g. LECROY,WAVERUNNER9254M,LCRY4751N40408,9.2.0

print('Waiting for trigger...')
o.wait_for_single_trigger() # Halt the execution until there is a trigger.

data = o.get_waveform(n_channel=1)

print(data['waveforms'])

I cannot for the life of me figure out why if anyone has a solution that would be greatly appreciated.

I frequently download oscilloscope curve data using pyvisa. Twice I did run into trouble:

For downloading the curve the oscilloscope must be in the stop state (thats why I always use single shot to aquire the data). In the run state downloading curve data always fails.
Damaged USB port in the oscilloscope. Using the same device over a network cable did function without any issues.

So make shure the oscilloscope is not acquiring new data while doing the download and try using a network cable instead of the USB-Port.

Yeah I think there was some weird connection issue going on. I tried again today and its been working smoothly without any issues. Have no idea what the problem was or what the solution is but its working now and I'm not going to question that.
